# Передача переменных из php в js и обратно, без вывода

Tags: php, javascript, pure_js

Доброго всем времени суток.

1. Имеем код php, в котором `$x = 5`, нужно передать значение `$x` в код JS, который написан ниже на странице, скажем, приравнять его к переменной "`qwe`".
2. Имеем код JS, в котором `var qwe = 3`, нужно передать значение "`qwe`" в код php, который написан ниже на странице, скажем, приравнять его к переменной `$x`.

p.s. Увы и ах, в инете встретил море подобных решений, но с PHP->JQ->PHP.

Comment: "код написан ниже на странице"...
Вы понимаете, как исполняется код? что код на php генерирует страничку, и лишь потом браузер исполняет ее?
Что на момент, когда будет исполнятся javascript код, php код уже давно отработал?

Comment: Если не нравится JQ или прототайп или прочие фреймворки, специально для велосипедистов-строителей я ввел тэг pure_js. =|

Comment: да нет, я не о pure_js даже а о формулировке "Передача переменных из php в js и обратно..."<br>
Для меня это выглядит прмиерно как - я вообще ничего не шарю, но мне нужен код <b>а вдруг пойму</b>

Comment: Возможно, это еще один @Prikol. А может, ему правда нужен код, вдруг поймет? ^.^

Comment: @Prikol - это особый случай ^^<br>
Я бы сказал - клиника

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var qwe = Math.random()*99+1;
function loadXMLDoc()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// Для свежих эксплореров и приличных браузеров
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// для старых эксплореров
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)//Запрос обработан на стороне сервера и ждет обработки на клиенте *
    {
    qwe = xmlhttp.responseText;// присваиваем переменной qwe значение, которое выплюнул скрипт ***
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","php_script.php?qwe="+qwe,true);//готовим ГЕТ запрос на наш пи-эйч-пи-шник. Заодно пересылаем нашу переменную на сервер. **
xmlhttp.send();//отправляем.
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Получить переменную</button>

</body>
</html>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$x = rand(1,100);
$js_qwe = $_GET['qwe'];
print($x);
?>
```

Разбор полетов.
`*` - это ответ от сервера на наш запрос
`**` - здесь мы пересылаем переменную qwe из JS->PHP
`**` здесь мы осуществляем PHP->JS

P.S. W3Schools вам в [помощь](http://w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp).

P.P.S. Кстати о JS, который ниже на странице.

```
<?php $x = rand(1,100); ?>
//....SOME_CODE
<script>
var qwe = <?=$x?>;
</script>
```

В пункте 2 такой номер не прокатит. Только через Ajax

Comment: @knes - это все круто, но если у аффтара возник такой вопрос значит ему нужно просто разобраться что такое ajax и с чем его едят, ато<br><br>
увы и ах, в инете встретил море подобных решений, но с PHP->JQ->PHP...<br><br>
Ну LOL же, врядли он поймет хоть половину того что тут написано %)

Comment: Ну я же в свое время понял! Правда ни фига не запомнил, поэтому каждый раз лажу на W3, если кто-то просит чистого нативного аякса. Я, кстати, еще застал, когда там были разные версии ActiveX, а конструкция для HTTPRequest была трехэтажная... Были времена:)

Comment: Ну "разные версии ActiveX" это из разряда "we love you IE" ^^<br>
выплюнул скрипт - улыбнуло xD

Comment: улыбнуло xD// Потому что передал - это когда много, в json/XML и с обработкой ошибок. А когда плейнтекстом одно значение - это именно выплюнул.

Comment: ну зачем было бочку катить, просто бывает застреваешь на чем то :-) код понятен, пойду разбираться. СПАСИБО!

Comment: Посидели бы вы тут подольше, поняли бы почему бочку покатил...

Comment: Алекс, вообще-то Михалеф появился тут раньше месяца на 2...